# Adding columns without breaking formula in template

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using a [template](http://trumpexcel.com/2015/03/excel-leave-tracker/) from Trump Excel.

I want to add four columns just before the name column.

I went through the comments from the wesbite and managed to get a sample with an additional column from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsubvcfounytzqn/Excel-Leave-Tracker-2016-TrumpExcel%20Additional%20Column.xlsm?dl=0) but everything seems so difficult and this sample does not look like the original one. Missing end columns.

I tried inserting the columns in the beginning and the macro breaks. I fixed the macro by changing the following line:

```
LeaveTracker.Range(Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 - 29), Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 + 1)).Hidden = False
```

and changing the range to D3 after adding EmpID, Rep, Col3 before Name.

This stops the error but now, the dates has a problem. Jan shows only 28 starts from 4th and Feb has other problems and the rest of the months also exhibit date problems.

The Excel file [Download](http://trumpexcel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Excel-Leave-Tracker-2016-TrumpExcel_Custom-Range_v1.xlsm).

The complete macro.

```
Sub showcalendar()
LeaveTracker.Columns("B:NI").Hidden = True
LeaveTracker.Range(Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 - 29), Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 + 1)).Hidden = False
End Sub
```

The date formula.

```
=IF(AND((COLUMN()-1)>31*($A$3-1),MONTH(DATE($A$2+INT(($A$3+$A$1)/12),INT((COLUMN()-1)/31.001)+$A$1,ROUNDUP(MOD(COLUMN()-1,31.001),0)))=ROUNDUP(MOD($A$1+$A$3-1,12.01),0)),ROUNDUP(MOD(COLUMN()-1,31.001),0),"")
```

[image: The dates and formula]

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? Some here may not be willing to download a macro enabled excel file for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @asp8811 Good shout there, This is all I there is in the macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some complex formulas in the dates and days of the week. They are using the COLUMN function which returns the current cell's column number.

First, you need to stick with the change you made to the macro, but change `Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 + 1)` to `Columns(Range("A3").Value * 31 + 4)`

Second, you need to adjust the line `LeaveTracker.Columns("B:NI").Hidden = True` to reflect the changes that you are making. I believe the columns should be "E:NM"

Third, the dates and days of the week all have complex formulas in them. They are using the COLUMN() function, which returns the cell's column number, to determine the day of the month. You will need to adjust this. Do a Find and Replace on "COLUMN()-1" and replace it with "COLUMN()-4"

That should fix several things and get you moving.

Edit to add: 
Right click on the scroll bar at the bottom and choose "Format Control..." 
Change the target cell link to 'Leave Tracker'!$D$1

That should fix almost everything. The only issue now is that you'll have a blank column or two at the end of the month if it is less than 31 days.

Comment: I followed the instructions and to an extent it worked. However, 3 days have moved to the next month. Will post the screenshots

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. Please see the first step and the addition. Changing the +1 to +4 in that part of the macro is what fixes the problem you are having. The sheet should be working now.

Comment: Thanks asp8811 but looks like this solved the problem. I will do a couple of checks and accept this answer. Also, get back with additional doubts if you don't mind.

Comment: Don't mind at all. Just respond with any other questions you have. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you, this is fantastic. Everything is working fine. Was struggling for an entire day, trying different combinations, as I have never worked with Excel macros/formulas

Comment: Hey, back again. Apologies for asking more help, any chance I can get help on the formula for the column "Leaves Applied" (Total leaves) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b9g174g3xu6tbo/Excel-Leave-Tracker-2016-Additional%20Column%20-%20Copy.xlsm?dl=0  Not sure why is it so complicated :-/

Comment: There are cells in row 3 that originally had a formula in them. I would replace those first. Then, use this formula =SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($B8,0,1,1,372)<>"")*(IF(OFFSET($B8,0,1,1,372)=$NS$6,0.5,1)*(OFFSET($B$3,0,1,1,372)))) in NK8 and use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter it as an array formula. Then drag and drop to NK11. When you use arrays in formulas like this, you have to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER.

Comment: asp8811 cannot thank you enough for you time. I downloaded the file again and yes there was that formula on there. Will fix that bit (I hope, as I am not sure of hiding it). I was thinking isn't the column NL8 instead of NK8?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106630/discussion-between-vivian-lobo-and-asp8811).